# How to clear startmenu folder variable value if the user click back button in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I newbie to NSIS.I have create exe file using this script.

If the user selected any subfolder like accessories,games,after that user wants to remove that subfolder is not possible in this shortcut menu.
For eg.If the user select the shortcut under Accessiories[as below picture],and suppose user click back button and again come to this page still it show like this,
Accessories/myapp.

My question:
User select any folder after that user click the button and again come this page mean it will display my application only.there is no appending of existing sub folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!include MUI2.nsh
Var MyStartFolder
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_PRE ForceStartFolder
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU DefaultPage $MyStartFolder
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Function ForceStartFolder
StrCpy $MyStartFolder "Forced_$(^Name)"
FunctionEnd
```